# Displaying a char pointer using similar syntax as a char array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, output

So, in an array, you can use [i] to move from one index to the next. Im aware that you can do something similar by incrementing the memory address of a pointer:

```
pMyPointer++;
```

But can you loop through a pointer using similar syntax as for an array (using [ ])? I'm new to C, so if you can, why, how does it work, and what's the correct syntax? I imagine it would look something like:

```
#define MAXLENGTH 5

...

char* pMyString = myString;

for(int i = 0; i < MAXLENGTH; i++)
    printf("%c", *pMyString[i])
```

Comment: You don't need `*`, it should just be `pMyString[i]`

Comment: `ptr[i]` is equivalent to `*(ptr + i)`

Comment: @Barmar I see, thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define MAXLENGTH 5

...

char* pMyString = myString;//No &: if myString is an array, it's already an address, so no & needed

for(int i = 0; i < MAXLENGTH; i++)
{
    printf("%c", *pMyString); ++pMyString;
}
```

Or you could `printf("%c",pMyString[i]);`.

The bottom line is as in the comments above: you can write `ptr[i]` as `*(ptr+i)` or vice versa -- they amount to the same thing.

Here's a nicer way of doing it:

```
while (*pMyString)
{
  printf ("%c",*pMyString); ++pMyString;
}
```

The reason this is cool is that you're no longer bound to MAXLENGTH -- it will keep going till it gets to `'\0'`, the end of string character.

Comment: The first one prints the first character five times.

Comment: “if myString is an array, it's already a pointer” — This is wrong. Arrays and pointers are distinct types in C. Arrays can be implicitly *converted* to pointers, but that doesn’t make them identical to pointers.

Comment: Ian, Konrad, your concerns are addressed. That Guy, is this the answer you were hoping for?